# Many to many relationship with additional filters on the middle table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a schema like the one below:

`CREATE TABLE user (id integer, name text);
CREATE TABLE link (id1 integer, id2 integer, type integer);
CREATE TABLE address (id integer, address text);`

The `link` table is an generic join table: we use the `type` column to restrict the join between two entities (eg. type=1001 for user to address relationship).
I would like to express the following query using SQLAlchemy:

`SELECT *
FROM user
JOIN link ON
    link.id1 = user.id
    AND link.type = 1001
JOIN address ON
    address.id = link.id2`

That's it, declaring additional filter (ie. `link.type = 1001`) in the secondary join parameter of the relationship .

I have the following SQLAlchemy definition:

`link = Table('link', db.metadata,
    Column('id1', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('core_user.user_id')),
    Column('id2', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('core_comm.id')),
    Column('type', INTEGER())
)`

`class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    __schema__ = 'public'
    id = Column('id', INTEGER(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', TEXT())
    addresses = relationship('Address', secondary=link)`

`class Address(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    __schema__ = 'public'
    id = Column(INTEGER(), primary_key=True)
    address = Column(Text())`

It joins correctly between the 3 tables and I get records, but I don't find a way to apply additional filters on the secondary join. I'm not even sure it's the right way to go.

Ideally, I would like to get an `addresses` field in the User object, which would be a list of Address object, potentially back-referenced.

Any hints ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read [`Specifying Alternate Join Conditions`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions) section of the documentation. The code below should do it:

```
addresses = relationship('Address',
        secondary=link,
        primaryjoin=id==link.c.id1,
        secondaryjoin="and_(link.c.id2 == Address.id, link.c.type == 1001)",
        backref="users",
        )
```